# Can Mobile Games use Fragments instead of SurfaceViews?

Tags: java, android, architecture, mobile

All the tutorials of mobile games for android (such as [this one](https://youtu.be/6prI4ZB_rXI?t=68)), use the  to display game objects. Most other applications tend to use an `Activity > Layout Resource` architecture.

The guide explains why he uses a `Activity > SurfaceView Subclass` architecture because of threading and canvasing [at this point in the video](https://youtu.be/6prI4ZB_rXI?t=80).

- Could you use fragments to have take care of threading and displaying game objects?
- If you can, why is using a SurfaceView preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience in game developing, when making a game for multiple platforms, its easier to organise everything in such a way that works for most of them.

In this case, using a `SurfaceView` is like telling to android "Give me a rectangular area on the screen, where I will draw custom graphics". This is very similar to how game development is being done on other platforms, by creating a window, or otherwise asking the OS for an area on the screen to show all the graphics.

I don't have much experience with fragments, but from what I remember, they are very tied to android's app lifecycle. Using fragments means one has to develop primarily on android, and be familiar with how it works. In theory, that works, and if someone is familiar enough, they could use fragments.

However, most people out there use libraries or tools, that already work in a platform-agnostic way, which would make it more cumbersome to make them work with fragments instead.

At the end of the day, if they work for you, use them. In the past I've made a video game that was using android's `Activity`, without any subclasses. Why? Because I found it a fun thing to do.